# PyQt6 vtk integration

Tags: python, pyqt

How do I add a vtk renderer to my PyQt application?
I've tried the OpenGl widget but it doesn't seem to work.
I've also tried

```
QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
```

Comment: What exactly happened when you tried the [vtk pyqt examples](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/#pyqt)? Please provide a [mre].